# Xcode 14 Previews not showing View dimensions in previews anymore

Tags: xcode

Xcode previews isn't showing view dimensions in the "selectable" mode. Does anyone know how to re-enable them?

I tried going on Editor>Canvas>Show View Bounds, which I expected to fix the problem but that did nothing to my knowledge. I also tried going on Preferences>General and found nothing.

Comment: I have the same issue so I [asked on Apple Developer forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/724633).

Answer (score 0):

You should select 2 option from the left, to make bounds visible

[Hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIP7w.png)